# Private inheritance and implicit conversion

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

I have a class that inherits privately from `std::string`, and adds some functions. I want to be able to use this class just like `std::string`, so I am trying to define an implicit conversion operator (`operator string()`). However, I keep getting `inaccessible base` error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class Test:private string {
    int _a;
    public:
    operator string() {
        return "hello";
    }
};

int main() {
    Test t;
    if(t == "hello") {
        cout<<"world\n";
    }
}
```

Error:

```
trial.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
trial.cpp:15:13: error: ‘std::basic_string<char>’ is an inaccessible base of ‘Test’
 if(t == "hello") {
         ^
```

Questions:

1. Is it a bad idea to define such a conversion? Does this break any recommended programming practices?
2. How can I make this work?

EDIT: Clang was more helpful

```
trial.cpp:8:5: warning: conversion function converting 'Test' to its base class 'std::basic_string<char>' will never be used
    operator string() {
    ^
trial.cpp:15:8: error: cannot cast 'Test' to its private base class 'basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >'
    if(t == "hello") {
       ^
trial.cpp:5:12: note: declared private here
class Test:private string {
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Post full error messages in the future please.

Comment: "hello" is not a std::string.

Comment: One way I imagine I could make it work is by using public inheritance, and making the derived class ``final``. I do not have any additional memory allocated in the derived class, so the destructor not being called shouldn't(?) be an issue..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A conversion function to a private base class defeats the purpose of private inheritance. That's part of the reason why the standard forbids this kind of behavior:

> A conversion function is never used to convert a (possibly cv-qualified) object
>   to the (possibly cv-qualified) same object type (or a reference to it), **to a (possibly cv-qualified) base class of that type (or a reference to it)**, or to (possibly cv-qualified) `void`.

If you want access to the base class you should make the inheritance public. This keeps the code readable and comprehensive for others who may have to maintain it.

Comment: There is an unwritten rule that stl classes shouldn't be derived from, right? Is this an exception where that rule could be broken? As I mentioned in other comments,  do not override any ``std::string`` functions, I do not have any additional memory allocated, and I can make my class ``final``.

Comment: @user2308211 It's not that they shouldn't be derived from, it's that most of the classes (including `std::string`) were never made with the intention of being derived from. You can see this from the lack of virtual functions (including most importantly the lack of a virtual destructor). So if you were to delete a `std::string*` to a `Test` instance, you would have undefined behavior whether or not `Test` was `final`. You should consider that and the possibility of other people using `Test` without knowing that. This is the only main reason why I would vote against this kind of inheritance.

Comment: @0x499602D2 That's primarily an argument against using the class polymophically, or rather *storing* it polymorphically -- but not against inheritance per se. The two are not always coupled. Still, even apart from that there are often better alternatives than inheritance in order to add functionality. **The STL itself is the prime idiomatic example**: in contrast to libraries like the Java Collection Framework, the STL uses no inheritance, yet it is more powerful, as functionality can be extended much more freely by algorithms.

Good answer, by the way!

Comment: @TheOperator I agree, the problem I see with inheritance in this case is the *possibility* of others storing the class polymorphically. The OP can use aggregation but a particular caveat in this case is that `std::string`'s `operator==` is a function template and thus implicit conversions will not be considered, leaving us in the same place as before.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways I know to do it that suck, but still work. It isn't really implicit, though...

The less terrible way is explicitly calling the operator:

```
if(t.operator string() == "hello")
```

The more terrible way is a c-style cast.

```
if (*(string*)&t == "hello")
```

Note that this performs a `static_cast` to the base class pointer, not its evil sibling the `reinterpret_cast`.

From the [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) on explicit cast:

> pointer or reference to a derived class is additionally allowed to be cast to pointer or reference to unambiguous base class (and vice versa) even if the base class is inaccessible

Comment: One way to make it implicit would be use public inheritance, right? I do not override any ``std::string`` functions, I do not have any additional memory allocated, and I can make my class ``final``, thus preventing others from inheriting. Does that leave any reasons why public inheritance would still be bad?

Comment: @user2308211 Not that I'm aware of, but that doesn't mean there are reasons I am not aware of.

Comment: I'm keeping the answer unaccepted for a little bit, just in case somebody comes up with something. But thanks for the answer

Comment: @user2308211 I just wrote this to put the information here. It's a very interesting question, and I hope that someone can come up with a good solution to it.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Is it a bad idea to define such a conversion? Does this break any recommended programming practices?

Yes, inheriting a class that was not designed for it is generally a bad idea. It seems like the approach ("inherit") to your problem ("add some functions") originates from other programming languages where inheritance is common practice, for example Java.

In C++ where you have value semantics and an entire range of powerful abstraction mechanisms, inheritance often creates more problems than it solves, because some functions may not be virtual, and in order to store the object polymorphically, you must use dynamic allocation.

> How can I make this work?

Is there a reason why you don't use the standard C++ way -- global functions? They have a lot of advantages: they can be added without changing the class and without forcing users to use a different class (your derived one) and they increase encapsulation by limiting the number of member functions (which have direct access to the class internals).

Comment: This is private inheritance. So I don't know why you say it was a bad idea to inherit..

Comment: The points I mentioned apply to inheritance in general. Can you maybe add to your initial post what you exactly want to achieve, i.e. what functionality you want to add to `std::string` that cannot be added otherwise?

Comment: Any functionality that I needed could've been done using simple functions. But I don't think that's the point.

Comment: I may misunderstand your question, but since one part of it is about programming practice, I see it appropriate to point out alternative designs. Generally you should choose the relationship that does the job but has the lightest coupling, and that would apply to free functions in this case.

Comment: By inheriting from *string*, you have told the compiler that "Test" *is-a* string. By doing it private, you have said "But don't tell anyone". And by explicitely coding a cast operator you again want it *to be* a "string"..... C++ requires you to be a bit more decisive......    If any of *string*'s methods are not applicable to your class that is a strong hint that *Test* **is in fact not a string**, but maybe should have one as a member variable.

Comment: If ``std::string`` was virtual, I'd happily derive publicly. Test is indeed a string.