# User-defined conversion operator to inaccessible base class

Tags: c++, language-design

Why not allow user-defined conversion to base class (or reference to it) when base is inacessible: `protected` or `private`?

When there is a class `D` and its `public` base `B`, there is an implicit rule to bind references to `B` (`B&` or `B&&`, possibly cv-qualified) to objects of the class `D`, so the user-defined conversion to `B&` doesn't make sense. But when the base class is `protected` or `private`, the implicit rule is not applicable anymore. So why not allow to use user-defined conversion to `B&` (or `const B&` or `B&&` etc.)?

Comment: Could you give an example of a conversion that you want to do, but it is prohibited?

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking. Please provide an example demonstrating the problem, a [mcve].

Comment: @dasblinkenlight it is not prohibited, but never considered by compilers, because of current rules.

Comment: @Rakete1111 it is very clear what I am asking. For those, who knows, that user-defined conversion to base class operator is never executed as part of the conversion sequence.

Comment: @StupidQuestions Why would a user-defined conversion operator not be chosen by overload resolution? Example please.

Comment: Why should it be allowed?

Comment: @rex because there is no ambuiguity what to use: implicit rule or user-defined conversion operator. Why shouldn't it be allowed then?

Comment: Just because it would be doable/possible doesn't mean it should be done. *Why* do you believe it should be allowed?

Comment: @StupidQuestions not true. Implicit conversion to protected or private base classes is still considered. It's just prohibited to make use of it. That's why you can't provide a user defined conversion for it.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I know that explicit conversion to inaccessible base is still possible. But how to distinguish between situations when implicit conversion is considered, but the use of it is prohibited and when implicit conversion is not considered?

Comment: @StupidQuestions that should be another question and deserves a real question entry rather than being a comment.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb this question seems to be not stupid for me. Unfortunately, my name doesn't allow me to ask not stupid questions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35806702/1460794

Comment: @rex thanks, I've seen that answer. Maybe I want to do something when my derived is bound to the base, thats why I make the base private/protected and write operator, which converts to the base.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is allowed, nothing in the Standard prohibits this. But it just states that such a conversion operator will never be used. [`[class.conv.fct]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.conv.fct#1):

> A conversion function is never used to convert a (possibly cv-qualified) object to the (possibly cv-qualified) same object type (or a reference to it), to a (possibly cv-qualified) base class of that type (or a reference to it), or to (possibly cv-qualified) void.

Overload resolution will always prefer the base class constructor over a conversion operator, and the conversion operator will never be called, so it is unnecessary for implicit conversions. Access checking is always done after overload resolution, so the the conversion operator is never considered.

```
struct B {
    B() = default;
    B(const B&) = default;
    B& operator=(const B&) = default;
};

struct D : protected B {
    operator B() { return *this; }
};

int main() {
    D d;
    B b = d; // (1)
    b = d; // (2)
}
```

For (1), the copy constructor `B(const B&)` is a better match then converting `D` to `B` using a conversion operator ([`[over.match.ctor]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match#ctor-1)), so that constructor will be chosen. But only now is access checked, and because the `B`'s copy constructor is `protected`, it doesn't compile.

For (2) almost the exact same thing. `B& operator=(const B&)` is chosen by overload resolution because it is a better match than to call the user defined conversion operator of `D`. But now `B`'s assignment operator is also `protected`, and so you can't access it outside of `D`, and your code doesn't compile.

That's just how overload resolution works, as far as I know that is the only reason.

Comment: "It is allowed, nothing in the Standard prohibits this" you may read "not allowed" as "not used". It is just inaccuracy in the wording.